# Conveying "he or she" with "il ou elle", "his or her" with "à lui ou à elle", etc

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, noms, écriture-inclusive

I am trying to convey the following paragraph for a tutorial.

> **The reader** will know how to work with finite combinations of numbers, but what is less likely is **that he or she** will be familiar with the interpretation and use of limiting processes.

Here are my attempts.

> **Le lecteur** saura comment travailler avec des combinaisons finies de nombres, mais ce qui est moins probable, c'est **qu'il** sera familier avec l'interprétation et l'utilisation des limites.
>
> **Le lecteur ou la lectrice** saura comment travailler avec des combinaisons finies de nombres, mais ce qui est moins probable, c'est qu**'il ou elle** sera familier avec l'interprétation et l'utilisation des limites.

As another example:

> So, our ancestor decides to step-off the length of the object using
> his or her feet since most people have similar foot lengths.
>
> Ainsi, notre ancêtre décide de réduire la longueur de l'objet en
> utilisant ses pieds à lui ou à elle car la plupart des gens ont des longueurs de pied
> similaires.

Do turns like **Le lecteur ou la lectrice**, **il ou elle**, **à lui ou à elle" sound weird in French?

Comment: This doesn't sound weird, but if you have a long text it may become really heavy and bothering. Maybe you should read about "écriture inclusive" also.

Comment: @Laure Tu as parlé ici et ailleurs des événements qui ont ébranlé SE. Est-ce que tu peux me dire de quoi s'agit-il ? Merci !

Comment: @Laure I guess it is this : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nous ne sommes pas habitués dans le texte français à ces nouvelles pratiques qui prennent en compte un féminin ; on voit cela à partir de cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+lecteur+ou+la+lectrice+aura%2Cle+lecteur+aura&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cle%20lecteur%20aura%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cle%20lecteur%20aura%3B%2Cc0). D'ailleurs, on peut se demander pourquoi on n'utiliserait pas la conjonction « et » au lieu de « ou ».

Le fait que ces formes puissent donner une impression de quelque chose d'inhabituel, et pour l'instant ce sera le cas, n'est pas un inconvénient majeur, on s'habitue à tout ; ce qui est important c'est qu'elles donnent une impression de précision extrême, de détail non pris en compte de façon plus générale, une impression de longueur triviale. La même situation se retrouve dans des contextes comme ceux qui découlent des phrases suivantes.

- Demain ce mari et sa femme iront au restaurant. (*sauf en vue d'un effet de style, « ce couple »*)
- On écrira les lettres a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z en haut de la page, en ligne et une fois. (*les lettres de l'alphabet*)

Bien sûr, lorsqu'on lit le traditionnel « le lecteur saura …» on n'a pas de doute que les personnes dont il est question ne sont pas restreintes à celles du sexe masculin ; je crois que l'on peut même dire que par delà le contexte grammatical le mot « lecteur » acquiert déjà dans l'esprit du lecteur (de la lectrice) une généralité qui contredit sa nature de nom masculin du fait qu'elle est inclusive des personnes de sexe féminin, cela par la simple nécessité que ce ne peut pas être autrement ; cela ne fait aucun doute lorsque l'on parle des « *lecteurs d'un quotidien* ». On  perçoit donc déjà ce terme, « le lecteur », en dépit de son genre, comme un nom de genre mixte. De là à une redéfinition de « lecteur » en « quelqu'un qui lit » au lieu de « celui qui lit » il n'y a qu'un pas à franchir (ce que les anglais n'ont possiblement jamais eu à faire comme dans leur langue ce point de vue se trouve déjà dans un passé très lointain et était probablement déjà une caractéristique de l'anglo-saxon).

Toujours du point de vue du style, je ne pense pas que ce soit extravagant. Je ne vois pas d'autre objection que celle que je formule ci-dessus et je n'ai aucune base que je puise juger saine pour conseiller l'utilisation de la forme traditionnelle plutôt que la forme inclusive et vice versa. Cette question demande une étude sérieuse dont la conclusion devra être de régler la question une fois pour toute. Tout ce que j'entrevois comme option c'est celle de s'en tenir à la tradition tant qu'une solution vraiment satisfaisante n'est pas disponible.

Le cas du pronom ne permet pas du tout, il me semble, une inclusion tacite acceptable comme dans le cas du nom (ce qui n'est pas une solution de toute façon) ; la question devient plus épineuse pour les pronoms ; on voit cela à partir d'un ngram ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+ou+elle&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20ou%20elle%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cil%20ou%20elle%3B%2Cc0)) qui montre que depuis 1960 il y a eu une montée en flèche de l'utilisation du choix inclusif. L'identification de « il » avec le masculin est écrasante, ce qui expliquerait la préférence pour « il ou elle ». Il ne sera pas trouvé trop inhabituel donc, bien que les objections faite pour le choix de deux noms restent valides à mon avis pour les pronoms.  Remarquons que pour ce qui est du pronom en fonction attributive et en fonction de complément d'objet indirect, une bizarreté du français le rend idéal.

- **Le lecteur ou la lectrice** saura comment travailler  et **il ou elle** choisira ce qui **lui** plait.

Comment: @Dimitris Comment voulez-vous que les gens aient l'habitude de cette forme lorsqu'on ne la trouve pas et que par le passé on a trouvé « le lecteur »  à sa place? C'est ce que le ngram montre  ; la déduction me semble être une conclusion simple.

Comment: @Dimitris C'est vrai que ça ne fait qu'une vingtaine d'années que nous discutons de la prise en compte du genre dans la langue.  Le débat est très animé depuis une dizaine d'années et les avis très partagés mais intéressant. Pour ce qui est de lecteur, il y en a, même parmi les plus revendicatifs  qui considèrent que ça rentre dans les masculins génériques. Tu seras peut-être  intéressé par [cet article](https://theconversation.com/francaises-francais-le-langage-inclusif-nest-pas-une-nouveaute-104622) pour une perspective historique.

Comment: @Dimitris [Celui-ci aussi](http://www.slate.fr/story/171663/titiou-langage-ecriture-inclusive-eliane-viennot-mise-a-jour) permet de démarrer la réflexion si elle nouvelle pour toi, mais discutes avec tes collègues à la fac, tu verras tout le monde y va de son point de vue.  La rédaction des revues scientifiques (du moins dans les domaines littéraires et sociologiques, je sais qu'en science c'est différent) est obligé de prendre en compte ces problèmes. Même la presse évolue.

Comment: @Laure Merci ! Je me demande si le mot doctoresse et le mot autrice existent en français qui et pourquoi les a "supprimés". Est-ce que je peux poser la question dans FSE ?

Comment: @Dimitris Les deux mots existent. [Doctoresse](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/doctoresse) est dans tous les dictionnaires, employé depuis le 19e s. pour une femme docteur en médecine. Autrice est dans [peu de dictionnaires](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/autrice) mais est très employé (je le rencontre régulièrement dans les articles de recherche). Avant de poser une question renseigne-toi. Il existe une foultitude d'articles sur le sujet en ligne.

Comment: [Autrice: la très vieille histoire d'un mot controversé](https://www.franceculture.fr/litterature/autrice-la-tres-vielle-histoire-dun-mot-controverse), [Autrice, le féminin qui gênait tant l'Académie française est tout sauf un néologisme](https://www.huffingtonpost.fr/2019/02/28/autrice-le-feminin-qui-genait-tant-lacademie-francaise-est-tout-sauf-un-neologisme_a_23680379/), [Auteure ou autrice?On ne trouve plus ces termes choquants comme dans les années 80»](https://www.liberation.fr/france/2019/02/20/auteure-ou-autrice-on-ne-trouve-plus-ces-termes-choquants-comme-dans-les-annees-80_1710520).

Comment: @Laure Merci encore ! Une pléthore de sources:-)! N'étant pas natif je ne comprends pas : Lecteur->Lectrice ; Auteur->Autrice. Qu'est-ce que aussi gênant pour l'Académie ?

Comment: @Laure Chose amusante: Hier, j'avais un débat avec une élève ingénieure à laquelle je me suis adressé en disant Madame. Elle m'a dit que, n'étant pas mariée, elle est toujours Mademoiselle. Je lui ai parlé de ladite "féminisation" de la langue française. Que les Allemands ont enlevé le mot Fraulein. Que l'état française a  effacé des documents administratifs le mot Mademoiselle. Que ça existe des formes  comme doctoresse, docteure, professeure, etc. J'ai terminé par pourquoi Mademoiselle et non "mondamoiseau" pour les homes. Je crois qu'elle était un peu choquée:-)!

Comment: @Dimitris Il y a toujours des gens qui sont en retard ou qui refusent d'avancer. Et des questions d'éducation aussi. Pour ton commentaire précédent je t'ai répondu [ici](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52067167#52067167).

Comment: @Laure Coquille stupide : l'État français (et pas française). Sorry:-)!